# how to iterate one value twice in for loop (Python)

Tags: for-loop, if-statement

I am having a problem in really simple program. My problem is that i lose value (y = 50 or 100 or 150) because at that time first condition is not valid. so how can i repeat loop for let say y = 50. (i don't want to use '=' e.g  `y< = (50+increment)` because this is just a dummy program.

thanks

```
increment = 0
b = 1
var = 0
for y in range(1,1000):
    if y>= increment and y< (50+increment):
        print(f'{y}  in List {b}')

    else:
        var = y
        increment += 50
        b+=1
```

Comment: Can you please be clearer in what you want. Also, copy and pasting your code results in a syntax error on my repl for the print statement.

Comment: I agree that it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, but why not throw in an elif for those values that you're losing?

Comment: hi to explain further: 
my output is like:  
48  in List 1
49  in List 1
51  in List 2
52  in List 2
53  in List 2

i'm loosing 50 in List 2. and similarly 100 in List 3

thanks for your time

Comment: Without more information, this seems a bit like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I can see why you're getting the result you are, but it's not clear why you're set on the the approach you currently have set up.